# Change color of JTabbedPane border

Tags: java, border, jtabbedpane, uimanager

I'm trying to change the color of the default blue-gray border on my JTabbedPane. You can see the border circled in the image below.

[image]

I want to make this a dark gray color. I've tried using the following `UIManager` properties (which result in the UI in the image above):

```
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.background", Color.decode(Colors.FACE_BG));
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.foreground", Color.decode(Colors.FONT_WHITE));
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.opaque", true); 
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.decode(Colors.TABLE_SELECTION));
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.border", BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.decode(Colors.DARK_GRAY), 1));
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: I have looked into the sources of methods
[MetalTabbedPaneUI.installDefaults()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalTabbedPaneUI.java#79)
and [BasicTabbedPaneUI.installDefaults()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTabbedPaneUI.java#358)
From that I guess the relevant UI-color-property for you is `"TabbedPane.borderHightlightColor"`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I added that property with my `DARK_GRAY` color constant - still the same result unfortunately!

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
nameOfYourComponent.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
// the second argument is thickness
```

Comment: Does not work. This will color the outer border of the pane, not what OP highlighted.